# Intermittent issue with Compare Functionality

Tags: cme, component, sites-9.5

We are using classic UI of Tridion 9.5. We are often facing an issue with compare functionality while comparing versions of Tridion items. It throws an error as shown in the screenshot. Only when the server is rebooted, the issue gets fixed (temporarily). The issue can occur again (it did several times in the past). Restarting Tridion services doesn't help, but the reboot of the server does help. As I ask this question, the issue is occurring in one of the 2 servers in our Live environment while the other server doesn't have this issue.

"Default Component Template" (uses Default Dreamweaver component design and Default finish actions) is used behind the Compare functionality of Component versions.

How can this issue be fixed?

[image]

(80040356) <tcm:Error ErrorCode="80040356" Category="18" Source="Kernel" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0"><tcm:Line ErrorCode="80040356" Cause="true"></tcm:Line></tcm:Error>
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {C676E871-FD04-11D4-BB61-005004D6D2D4} failed due to the following error: 80004005 Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL)).

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {C676E871-FD04-11D4-BB61-005004D6D2D4} failed due to the following error: 80004005 Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL)).

Comment: did you upgrade the tridion , if so can you share from which version you upgraded to Sites 9.5. are you facing this issue on all items , like components , pages etc

Comment: can you create new component and save few versions and try to compare see if that works. also please test without the default template , may be try with the component and page templates that you have for your application. May be you need to rebuild the new TBB from the Template builder. can you check if the MTSUser / password is proper on the COM+ and are you facing it on DEV / UAT or only on Live that to one one of the server as mentioned .Meanwhile if you want you can reach out to SDL support too.

Comment: Upgraded from Tridion 8.5. Yes, the issue occurs with all versioned items. As already mentioned, the server reboot fixes the issue (at least temporarily). Hence I don't think that issue was due to the Template that is executed behind the scenes. Also, the other node in our Live environment doesn't have this issue (as of now). The issue also occurs with newly created items. I have already contacted SDL support and been waiting for answer.